# Google Sheets complex formula or script is needed

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, conditional-formatting

I have trouble with creating a complex conditional formula in Google Sheets. Honestly, I feel there is a need for some script with a "for" cycle, but I'm not sure.

The task is the following. I have a table with countable and text data. Based on the values of the "Result" cells there could be the filled-in decision cell with a text either "OK" or "NOT OK". See the screenshot and google sheet file below.
Could you please help?

[link to the file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e43Uo00PCPNOkPJhVVDOaPN_ewhUYlfCpDYa27qBF_Y/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/172099/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results.

Comment: Please address the previous comment.  Further, your rules are confusing to follow and the content is not accessible to everyone when in a picture.  Please [edit] your question to include clearer instructions as text.  Note that **Rule 1** means that `"NOT OK"`  is returned for the sample data because of the AND.  You should approach your rules descriptions using math's order of operations.  Use brackets to make clear what is inclusive, exclusive, etc. **Rule 6** is unnecessary as those cells appear nowhere else in the rules ergo are already *ignored* etc.  Your examples should show results

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rows()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=if( 
  and( 
    rows(filter(B4:B6, len(A4:A6))) = rows(filter(B4:B6, B4:B6 >= 100%)), 
    rows(filter(B8:B10, len(A8:A10))) = rows(filter(B8:B10, regexmatch(B8:B10, "Acceptable|Excellent"))) 
  ), 
  "OK", 
  "NOT OK" 
)
```

See [rows()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093382) and [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).

Comment: Thanks, it works!